# How to plot based upon unique column values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm a beginner learning to use python to do data visualizations.
I found a really cool data set by the UN it is formatted like this:

```
Afghanistan 1975 2127   
Afghanistan 1985 3509   
Afghanistan 1995 1243   
Afghanistan 2005 1327
Albania 1975 4595   
Albania 1985 7880   
Albania 1995 2087   
Albania 2005 4254
etc...
```

Up until now, I've been parsing out individual countries with statements like this:

```
china = data[data.area == 'China']
```

This is fine for picking individual countries but now, I want to plot all of them. How could I go about that?
So far I've tried this but couldn't figure out how to make it work:

```
old_value = data.iloc[0]
for i in len(data):
    if data.iloc[i].area == old_value:
#         add to current set
    else:
#      create new set
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer for this question? Can you link to the data file?

Answer (score 0):

## Given your data

- Setup imports and dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# plot parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)

data = {'country': ['Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania', 'Albania'],
        'year': [1975, 1985, 1995, 2005, 1975, 1985, 1995, 2005],
        'value': [2127, 3509, 1243, 1327, 4595, 7880, 2087, 4254]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

       country  year  value
0  Afghanistan  1975   2127
1  Afghanistan  1985   3509
2  Afghanistan  1995   1243
3  Afghanistan  2005   1327
4      Albania  1975   4595
5      Albania  1985   7880
6      Albania  1995   2087
7      Albania  2005   4254
```

## Use `seaborn.barplot` with the `hue` parameter

```py
p = sns.barplot(x='year', y='value', hue='country', data=df)
```

[image]

### Horizontally

```py
p = sns.barplot(x='value', y='year', hue='country', data=df, orient='h')
```

[image]

## A separate plot for each country

- Using `plt.subplot(1, 2, i)` the rows times the columns should equal the number of unique countries or +1 if there are an odd number.

```py
max_value = df.value.max() + 100  # + 100 to add padding at the top of the plot; 100 is an arbitrary value and can be removed
for i, country in enumerate(df.country.unique(), 1):  # iterate through each unique country
    data = df[df.country == country]  # filter by country
    plt.subplot(1, 2, i)  # rows, columns, i: plot index beginning at 1
    sns.barplot(x='year', y='value', data=data)
    plt.ylim(0, max_value)  # set y-lim with max of the value column; makes it easier to compare countries
    plt.title(country)
```

[image]